# Dynamic form field in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have form with input field and check box and two buttons , buttons are for add and delete. But i here want to remove add button and want to show next field with just checking the check box.How can i do this?

```js
angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic'])
.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.data ={
       names:[{ name:""}]
   };
  
  $scope.addRow = function(index){
    var name = {name:""};
       if($scope.data.names.length <= index+1 && $scope.data.names.length<10){
            $scope.data.names.splice(index+1,0,name);
        }
    };
  
  $scope.deleteRow = function($event,index){
    if($event.which == 1)
       $scope.data.names.splice(index,1);
    }
})
```

```css
.button-dark{
  margin-top:10px;
}
.button-delete{
   display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 24px;
    height: 33px;
    top: -36px;
    right: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Multiple input</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic app</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form id="valueForm" ng-submit="saveValues(values)">
      <div  ng-repeat="name in data.names track by $index">
   <label class="item item-input" style="width: 92%">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" ng-model="data.names[$index].name">
      <ion-checkbox  ng-model="success.first"  ng-disabled="!data.names[$index].name" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;" class="checkbox-royal"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>
    <button type="button" class=" button-delete" ng-click="deleteRow($event,$index)" ng-disabled="$index == 0"><i class="ion-ios-minus-empty"></i></button>
   <input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last">
   
   </div> 
  </div>


       

        <button type="submit"  class="button button-dark button-shadow pull-right" style="">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use `ng-hide`, on the button using the `model` of `check-box`.
`<input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last" ng-hide="success.first">`

Comment: i don't wanna use button to add new field @Sravan

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **Add** Button and add `ng-click="addRow($index)"` to checkbox.. check below working snippet

```js
angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic'])
.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.data ={
       names:[{ name:""}]
   };
  
  $scope.addRow = function(index){
    var name = {name:""};
       if($scope.data.names.length <= index+1 && $scope.data.names.length<10){
            $scope.data.names.splice(index+1,0,name);
        }
    };
  
  $scope.deleteRow = function($event,index){
    if($event.which == 1)
       $scope.data.names.splice(index,1);
    }
})
```

```css
.button-dark{
  margin-top:10px;
}
.button-delete{
   display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 24px;
    height: 33px;
    top: -36px;
    right: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Multiple input</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic app</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form id="valueForm" ng-submit="saveValues(values)">
      <div  ng-repeat="name in data.names track by $index">
   <label class="item item-input" style="width: 92%">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" ng-model="data.names[$index].name">
      <ion-checkbox  ng-model="success.first"  ng-disabled="!data.names[$index].name" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;" class="checkbox-royal" ng-click="addRow($index)"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>
    <button type="button" class=" button-delete" ng-click="deleteRow($event,$index)" ng-disabled="$index == 0"><i class="ion-ios-minus-empty"></i></button>
   
   </div> 
  </div>


       

        <button type="submit"  class="button button-dark button-shadow pull-right" style="">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it not possible to keep check box checked? . The main issue i have faced with that i already used the same solution as you provide here , but i want to keep the checkbox checked.

Comment: Added code check now the checkbox wont remove..., there you can add any tick background image for checked checkbox... play around with css for label you will get that result... let me know